# I can't do the Debug on STM32 MCU

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm having a problem: I can't program and debug my STM32G050F6P6 on my PCB.

I talked to many people in order to solve it, but nothing to do.
If you want you can see the discussions by clicking [here](https://community.st.com/s/feed/0D53W00001x0RQaSAM?t=1671822636645).

To make a small summary:
with STM32Programmer I can program the MCU without problems (with the .elf file), but if I try to upload the code via STM32Cube IDE I get many problems (same thing for debugging).
I've already tried to change the debug and upload configurations in all possible ways, but NOTHING.

Now I tried to change the resistors that were located between the pins of the microcontroller and the connectors to which SWDIO and SWCLK of the ST-LINK/V2 are connected, and debugging goes with many problems (I remember that before changing the resistors the debugging).
Now that I've changed the resistors, from 1k to 20ohm, I can debug (SWD, Connect Under Rest or Software System Reset, 950khz), but the errors I get are these:

[image]

and:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-00449-g53fa0f7 (2022-06-09-09:42) [https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/OpenOCD]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : STLINK V2J40S7 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:3748
Info : Target voltage: 3.208388
Info : clock speed 950 kHz
Info : stlink_dap_op_connect(connect)
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x0bc11477
Info : STM32G050F6Px.cpu: Cortex-M0+ r0p1 processor detected
Info : STM32G050F6Px.cpu: target has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : STM32G050F6Px.cpu: external reset detected
Info : starting gdb server for STM32G050F6Px.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x1fff1654 msp: 0x20000e48
Info : device idcode = 0x10006456 (STM32G05/G06xx - Rev A : 0x1000)
Info : RDP level 0 (0xAA)
Info : flash size = 32kbytes
Info : flash mode : single-bank
Error: Failed to read memory at 0xfffffffe
Error: Failed to read memory at 0xfffffffe
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x1fff1654 msp: 0x20000e48
Info : Padding image section 0 at 0x080018c4 with 4 bytes (bank write end alignment)
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xf1000000 pc: 0x1fff1654 msp: 0x20000e48
Info : STM32G050F6Px.cpu: external reset detected
```

My question now is if I got the wiring diagram wrong.
Below you will find the image of the wiring diagram of the programming part:
[wiring diagram (programming part)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzhxG.png)

Since I changed those two 1k resistors of SWDIO and SWDCLK (R14 - R15) I get the error from the previous post.

Did I miss something in the wiring diagram?

Comment: The resistor in series with the capacitor on the reset line is very unusual.  Even the capacitor isn't usually required, and unless it is very small value then it will cause all kinds of problems because this is a bi-directional signal.  I suggest take them both off unless you find you really need them.

Comment: But note that questions about electronics have to be made on electronics.stackexchange.com (stackoverflow is only for software)

Comment: Post error text as text (copy & paste), not a _picture of text_.

Answer (score 3):

Addresses `0x1F......` are in the closed-source ROM bootloader, you can't debug that.  If you want to debug your application then you need to set the boot mode pins correctly so that it starts, not the ROM.  See [AN2606](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00167594-stm32-microcontroller-system-memory-boot-mode-stmicroelectronics.pdf) for instructions how to do that.